# Access Javascript in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, html, .net, google-chrome, dom

Well I am looking for a solution where I can access the DOM element / Javascript function in Chrome browser (which is **not embedded** in the app but a regular Chome browser) through .Net window application , in simple words same functionality provided by MSHTML to access DOM in Internet Explorer.

**I dont want to embed the Chrome browser using Webkit.Net in the desktop app.**

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you would want to be able to (for example) modify a web page being rendered in Chrome from an external application? 1. Why? 2. I have heavy doubts that it's possible.

Comment: For the Why ? In simple words I want to  pass on some data from a desktop app basically a incoming call(desktop app) number to the Chrome browser depending on which some action have to be taken on client side (web app).

Comment: I see. Your best bet is to have a server relay the data between the browser and the app. I can't imagine it work any other way due to security concerns.